# Problems Nesting UITextField within UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I have an array, we'll call it `itemsArray`, that contains instances of a class called `Item.` These `items` have properties of length, width, and height. `itemsArray` is also nested within another class (`questionnaire`) that also has a property called `activeItem`. Basically, the `activeItem` is an integer that returns a value that corresponds to the index of the `item` in `itemsArray` that is being edited at the time. Therefore, if I wanted to update the second `item` in `itemsArray`, I would set `activeItem` to 1 and go from there.

Now, I need to populate these length, width, and height properties of the items in `itemsArray`. To do so, I'm creating a tableView with a customized UITableViewCell. This UITableViewCell, let's call it `CustomTableViewCell,` has 3 UITextField properties corresponding to 3 UITextFields that I put on the storyboard, `lengthField`, `widthField`, and `heightField`. I'm having some trouble getting the values typed into the textfields to store with their corresponding instances of `item`. Here's some code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    self.cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"quantityCell"];
    [self.cell.lengthField addTarget:self action:@selector(lengthEdited:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
    return self.cell; 
}

- (void)lengthEdited:(id)sender{
CGPoint position = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.quantityTableView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.quantityTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:position];
[questionnaire setActiveItem: indexPath.row]; 
[[questionnaire.itemsArray objectAtIndex:activeItem]setItemLength self.cell.lengthField.text];
}
```

For simplicity's sake, the dimensions can be stored as strings. Now, I'm adding instances of `item` at runtime, and I'm trying to edited the dimensions of those instances shortly thereafter, but when I try to do that, only the last object in the tableView seems to respond properly. I've NSLog'd the `activeItem`, and I see that, whenever I edit a cell, it's setting `activeItem` to the value of indexPath.row, which is absolutely correct. However, when I also try to NSLog the value of `itemLength` in the `activeItem`, I get null values returned until I attempt to log the final item in array. Once I do that, regardless of which cell I edit, I get the value of the last item in that array's length.

Does anybody have an idea of what I'm doing wrong here? I'm hopelessly stuck. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be more simple if you use Tag property of textfield like

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    self.cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"quantityCell"];
    [self.cell.lengthField setTag:indexPath.row];
    [self.cell.lengthField addTarget:self action:@selector(lengthEdited:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
    return self.cell; 
}
```

then you can do it like

```
- (void)lengthEdited:(id)sender{

   UITextField *lengthTextField = (UITextField*)sender;
   NSInteger tag = lengthTextField.tag;
   [questionnaire setActiveItem: tag]; 
   [[questionnaire.itemsArray objectAtIndex:tag]setItemLength: lengthTextField.text];
}
```

But for this you should have correct Item object in active index.

Comment: That certainly helped retain the data. Thank you! Now my only problem is that scrolling makes my textviews go away :\